# Difference between raise Exception 'This is the error' and raise 'This is the error'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I've seen people doing both ways but I can't spot the difference between them:

```
raise Exception('This is the error')
```

and

```
raise 'This is the error'
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: `raise 'This is the error'` That doesn't work.  Where did you see it?

Comment: `raise Exception 'This is the error'` That doesn't work either.  Perhaps you meant `raise Exception('This is the error')`?

Comment: Long, long ago, one could raise any value as an exception, but I think that "feature" was eliminated in Python 2.0.

Comment: The `raise` statement in very old versions of Python was quite different than it is today; e.g., see https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/ref/raise.html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use either. The first is a syntax error:

```
>>> raise Exception "This is an error"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    raise Exception "This is an error"
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

while the second is a type error (you can't "raise" a `str` value):

```
>>> raise "this"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

The correct form would be to call the exception type with the error message as an argument:

```
raise Exception("this is the error")
```

In the case where the desired exception doesn't require an argument, raising the `Exception` type itself is equivalent to raising an instance created without an argument.

```
raise Exception   # equivalent to raise Exception()
```